# PHPExcel - reading row comments , text strike missing

Tags: php, excel

Am trying to read excel file with PHPExcel library

> https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

however when i read row then am not able to get comments on field and strikes on text also missing .

my code is

```
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$ftype = 'Excel2007';
$fname = 'data.xlsx';
$objexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fname);
$sdata = $objexcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
foreach ($sdata as $k=>$d) {
        print_r($d);  // output
}
```

so it output comments and strikes which are in data.xlsx file are missing .
any idea how to display and check if row have comments and strikes through text

Comment: I think its an array so use `print_r($d);`

Comment: ya updated , its array ., but still comments are missing and strikes

Comment: Check `print_r($sdata);`

Comment: ya i checked it have no comments data

Comment: It means you need to change `data.xlxs` or check it once again.

Comment: it have comments .... now am trying to write my own custom reader ... i check phpexcel and other dozens of those excel readers none have comments reading feature nor strikes ...